# ReactNative Expo different colors on exported APK

Tags: android, react-native, expo, react-native-paper

I have an Expo managed React Native project and when I do eas build to create an APK of my app and install it, the colors are very different from what I see when using Expo Go to preview the app. Any idea why this could be happening? I'm mostly using ReactNativePaper components.

`eas.json`

```
{
  "build": {
    "preview": {
      "developmentClient": true,
      "android": {
        "buildType": "apk",
        "gradleCommand": ":app:assembleRelease"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

`package.json`

```
{
  "name": "mobile",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-native-community/datetimepicker": "7.2.0",
    "@react-native-masked-view/masked-view": "0.2.9",
    "@react-native-picker/picker": "2.4.10",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^6.5.8",
    "@react-navigation/material-top-tabs": "^6.6.3",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.1.7",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.9.13",
    "@rneui/base": "^4.0.0-rc.7",
    "@rneui/themed": "^4.0.0-rc.8",
    "@tanstack/react-query": "^4.32.6",
    "@types/react": "~18.2.14",
    "base-64": "^1.0.0",
    "expo": "~49.0.7",
    "expo-file-system": "~15.4.4",
    "expo-image-picker": "~14.3.2",
    "expo-linear-gradient": "~12.3.0",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.6.0",
    "firebase": "^10.1.0",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.72.4",
    "react-native-linear-gradient": "^2.8.2",
    "react-native-paper": "^5.10.1",
    "react-native-root-toast": "^3.4.1",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "4.6.3",
    "react-native-screens": "~3.22.0",
    "react-native-shadow-2": "^7.0.8",
    "react-native-svg": "13.9.0",
    "react-native-tab-view": "^3.5.2",
    "typescript": "^5.1.3",
    "react-native-pager-view": "6.2.0",
    "expo-av": "~13.4.1",
    "expo-dev-client": "~2.4.10",
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "1.18.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.20.0"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

Screenshot(left-using expo go, right-built apk):
[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

This is likely due to the `Dark Mode` setting on the APK-built phone. To resolve this, `switch your phone's theme` to Light Mode or consider other theme-related adjustments.